# How to fix this leak?

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, nsoperationqueue, sharekit

I am getting a leak on the helper.offlineQueue line where I alloc a NSOperationQueue object. The problem is, I am not quite sure where to release it in this method...

```
+ (void)flushOfflineQueue
{
    // TODO - if an item fails, after all items are shared, it should present a summary view and allow them to see which items failed/succeeded

    // Check for a connection
    if (![self connected])
        return;

    // Open list
    NSMutableArray *queueList = [self getOfflineQueueList];

    // Run through each item in the quietly in the background
    // TODO - Is this the best behavior?  Instead, should the user confirm sending these again?  Maybe only if it has been X days since they were saved?
    //      - want to avoid a user being suprised by a post to Twitter if that happens long after they forgot they even shared it.
    if (queueList != nil)
    {
        SHK *helper = [self currentHelper];

        if (helper.offlineQueue == nil)
            helper.offlineQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];      

        SHKItem *item;
        NSString *sharerId, *uid;

        for (NSDictionary *entry in queueList)
        {
            item = [SHKItem itemFromDictionary:[entry objectForKey:@"item"]];
            sharerId = [entry objectForKey:@"sharer"];
            uid = [entry objectForKey:@"uid"];

            if (item != nil && sharerId != nil)
                [helper.offlineQueue addOperation:[[[SHKOfflineSharer alloc] initWithItem:item forSharer:sharerId uid:uid] autorelease]];
        }

        // Remove offline queue - TODO: only do this if everything was successful?
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[self offlineQueueListPath] error:nil];

    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect you should just do:

```
helper.offlineQueue = [[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] autorelease];
```

The SHK object itself should be retaining the queue and will release it when it is done.  The reference you are holding due to the alloc can be released immediately.